# problems with inserting data in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

```
$message=$_POST['answer'];
$message=nl2br($message);
$message=strip_tags($message, '<p><a><b><i><strong><em><code><sub><sup><img><ul><ol><li>');
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
$user=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$qry="INSERT INTO forum_rules (message,author,date) VALUES ($message,$user,'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result) {
echo "error inserting data into database";
} else { 
    ...
    }
```

this codes always outputs error inserting data into database and i don't see what i'm doing wrong. i hav also tried to do it without the date part but that didn't work tho. can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: What error message are you receiving ? What are the data types of the 3 columns ?

Comment: Well, you don't have any single quotes around `$message` or `$user` in the string for your query.

Comment: the error it says is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Jannes,'2012-06-10 18:33:17')' at line 1
note: the username is Owner Jannes so maybe it's the space in the name.

Comment: longtext tinytext and timestamp

Comment: Yeah. Even the MySQL error is confirming what I said. It's right there.

Comment: The message & user variables should be wrapped in single quotes. If you print out the $qry variable, what do you get?

Comment: thank you very much for the fast help. it were the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stated by Jared Farrish, this is probably caused by the lack of single quotes around the text variables.

```
VALUES ('$message','$user',
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
$qry="INSERT INTO forum_rules (message,author,date) VALUES ('$message','$user')";
```

Try this

Comment: No, that's not right. There's still no `'` around the values going into the database, eg, *within the string*.

Comment: I updated my ans.pls check this one